# Cost analysis for implementing a stack as an array?

Tags: algorithm, stack, time-complexity, big-o, amortized-analysis

[image]

Please Refer to answer 2 of the material above. I can follow the text up to that point. I always seem to loose conceptualisation when there's no illustration maybe due to the fact that I'm new to math notation.

I understand the cost for an expensive operation (double the array when the stack is full)

1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + ... + 2^i where i is the index of that sequence. So index 0 = 1, 1 = 2, 2 = 4 and 3 = 8.

I can see the sequence for costly operations but I get confused with the following explanation.

> Now, in any sequence of n operations, the total cost for resizing is
>   1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + ... + 2^i for some 2^i < n (if all operations are pushes
>   then 2^i will be the largest power of 2 less than n). This sum is at
>   most 2n − 1. Adding in the additional cost of n for
>   inserting/removing, we get a total cost < 3n, and so our amortised
>   cost per operation is < 3

I don't understand that explanation?

> the total cost for resizing is 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + ... + 2^i for some 2^i < n

What does it mean for some `2^i < n`

does it say that the number of operations n will always be larger than 2^i? and does n stand for the number of operations or the length of the array?

And the following I just don't follow:

> if all operations are pushes then 2^i will be the largest power of 2
>   less than n. This sum is at most 2n − 1.

Could someone illustrate this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`n` is the largest stack size, intrinsic array size at this moment is the least power of two `2^(i+1)>=n`, so the last operation of expansion takes `2^i<n` time.

For example, if array reaches size `n=11`, the last expansion causes grow from 8 to 16 with 8 items moved

About the second question: sum of geometric progression

```
1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + ... + 2^i = 2^(i+1) - 1
```

Comment: What about the last statement "if all operations are pushes then 2^i will be the largest power of 2 less than n. This sum is at most 2n − 1"? I don't understand that.

Comment: Specifically "2^i will be the largest power of 2 less than n"

Comment: `n` pushes create stack size `n`. What is size of array? Some power of 2. What power? That provides `2^(i+1) >= n` to accomodate stack items

Comment: I understand what you mean, I think it's the way the author explains his notation. Like does "2^i will be the largest power of 2 less than n" directly translate to `2^i<n`?

Comment: And `2^i<n` basically means lets say you are at 2^3 = 8, the size of the array will be 16. So `2^i<n` holds true. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, for my example `(2^3=8) < (n=11) < (2^*4 = 16)`